# Use ID from a table then use ID from that table to get data SQL

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

```
SELECT
    player.FirstName,
    player.LastName,
    team.teamName,
    TotalPoints,
    TotalRebounds,
    TotalAssists,
    TotalSteals,
    TotalBlocks
FROM playerstats
INNER JOIN player
    ON playerstats.PlayerID = player.PlayerID
```

I have a table called player (Player ID, firstname, lastname, team ID)
table called Team (teamID, teamName). I have a table called playerstat(which has playerID)

I want to list firstname, last name and team along with total points, rebounds, etc

I want to use the playerID to get the team Id then list the team name ... if that makes sense. Not sure how to do that.

Comment: Just add a `WHERE` clause?  What is wrong with your current query?

Comment: What's not working with your current query?

Comment: Where is the team table in your query? IOW, where are you getting team.teamName?

Comment: I get this error -- Unknown column 'team.teamName' in 'field list'

Comment: The team.teamName is in a Team table and the team ID is under the Player table. The playerstats table has only the playerID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your question, you don't indicate if the playerstats table has multiple rows per player, and you don't indicate what the team table's columns might be, but presuming that the playerstats table has multiple rows per player, and that you have a team table, you might give this a try. You will need to substitute the correct column names:

```
SELECT
    player.FirstName,
    player.LastName,
    team.teamName,
    sum(points) as TotalPoints,
    sum(rebounds) as TotalRebounds,
    sum(assists) as TotalAssists,
    sum(steals) as TotalSteals,
    sum(blocks) as TotalBlocks
FROM playerstats
INNER JOIN player
    ON playerstats.PlayerID = player.PlayerID
JOIN team
    ON team.id = player.teamID
GROUP BY player.FirstName, player.LastName,team.teamName
ORDER BY player.FirstName, player.LastName,team.teamName;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select P.FirstName,P.LastName,t.teamName,s.TotalPoints 
from Player P
join Team t on P.TeamId=t.TeamId
join playerstats s on P.PlayerId=s.PlayerId
```

Comment: Hi. While this might be an answer, it would help further readers, that stumble across this question, if you could add some explaination of what you did there. It might be their first stuff in `SQL` related stuff. So if you could find some time, it would be highly appreciated.